# Actionscript not running in nested MovieClips in Swf loaded into AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm loading content swfs into an Air App.

The swfs are loaded into the non-app sandbox, and any communication is via the parent/child sandbox bridge.

The swfs have timeline code. This code executes fine.

The swfs also have mcs on the timeline - any code inside these mcs, or any child mcs of these mcs, is ignored. Simple traces do not execute below the top level timeline of the loaded swfs.

I have tried naming the child mcs. I have tried exporting them in the library. Neither makes any difference.

When I run the swf standalone, I see my diagnostic traces. When I load the swf, I only see the traces for the top level timeline.

Air app is v1.5

Any clues? I've been bashing into this brick wall for several hours now...

Comment: I think I've tracked it to being related to a Type Conversion issue. If I give MCs a custom class to handle the code instead then I get an error 1034.

I'm playing with ApplicationDomain and so on but so far it's having no impact.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after approx 20 hours of testing different scenarios.

There appears to be a bug that can cause serial loaded swfs to behave as if they are in the same AppDomain / or lose all custom classes from library and stage elements.

In some tests I did it happened when 3 or more swfs were loaded, in other test cases I could load several before the problem arose - probably due to memory?

Changing from serial loading of the swfs (using the Event.COMPLETE or Event.INIT event to trigger the next loading) to concurrent loading has seemingly fixed the issue.

Who knows why? Bizarre.